# Sequel Pro Alternative for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, user-interface

Well my macbook pro is kind of not cutting it for me anymore and I have a perfectly good Windows Laptop I would actually rather use but I cannot find a reliable replacement for my SQL client. So I am looking for a replacement for SequelPro for Windows..

Ones I have Tried and Either Didn't like or found a few issues with.

Navicat - This one when left inactive for more than 15 minutes crashes.. I don't mind that it wants to disconnect but please do it gracefully with out locking up my system for a few minutes.

SQLyog - Works well but I would like something with atleast a free for non-commercial use. I don't do any freelance and rarely do I do any of my 'work' on my personal laptop.

So does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I've never had a problem with Navicat behaving the way you describe.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I use SQLYog at home and work.  It turns out they DO have a free open-source version, though sadly they've been trying to hide that fact for the last few years.

You can download the open-source version from https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community - just click the "Download SQLyog Community Version" link.

Comment: The free version does not support SSH connections.

Comment: It's true.  In fact, most of the benefit of moving up to the Enterprise edition (that I know of) is in all the additional ways you can connect to MySQL databases.

Comment: HeidiSQL has been the best fit for me. So many features and for free.

Comment: It is not as better as Sequel Pro. But It is ok.

Comment: You can still use SSH tunnel even in the community edition, `ssh -N -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remotehost.here, then connect to localhost as it's installed locally on your machine

Answer (score 39):

You say you've had problems with Navicat. For the record, I use Navicat and I haven't experienced the issue you describe. You might want to dig around, see if there's a reason for your problem and/or a solution, because given the question asked, my first recommendation would have been Navicat.

But if you want alternative suggestions, here are a few that I know of and have used:

MySQL has its own tool which you can download for free, called **MySQL Workbench**. Download it from here: http://wb.mysql.com/. My experience is that it's powerful, but I didn't really like the UI. But that's just my personal taste.

Another free program you might want to try is **[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)**. It's more similar to Navicat than MySQL Workbench. A colleague of mine loves it.

(interesting to note, by the way, that MariaDB (the forked version of MySQL) is currently shipped with HeidiSQL as its GUI tool)

Finally, if you're running a web server on your machine, there's always the option of a browser-based tool like **[PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)**. It's actually a surprisingly powerful piece of software.

Answer (score 7):

[Toad for MySQL by Quest](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) is free for non-commercial use. I really like the interface and it's quite powerful if you have several databases to work with (for example development, test and production servers).

From the website:

> Toad® for MySQL is a freeware development tool that enables you to rapidly create and execute queries, automate database object management, and develop SQL code more efficiently. It provides utilities to compare, extract, and search for objects; manage projects; import/export data; and administer the database. Toad for MySQL dramatically increases productivity and provides access to an active user community.

Comment: This wonderful tool has been replaced by an inferior one called "toad-edge". This link now opens that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) some features are not free, but you can get an evaluate license...